# What is the OpenCv equivalent of this Matlab code for Sobel edge detection?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

This is the Matlab code I want to replicate in OpenCv

```
e[~, threshold] = edge(I, 'sobel');
fudgeFactor = .5;
BWs = edge(I,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
figure, imshow(BWs), title('binary gradient mask');
```

This is my test image:

[Cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cv7J.png)

I have tried things like

```
blurred_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image,(3,3),0)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(blurred_gray,cv2.CV_8U,1,0,ksize=3) 
sobely = cv2.Sobel(blurred_gray,cv2.CV_8U,0,1,ksize=3)[2]
```

And the output I got is:

[sobelx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GY1u.jpg)

[sobely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ep3v.jpg)

I tried adding sobelx and sobely because I read they're partial derivatives, but the result image looks same as the above and varying the ksize didn't help.

This is the output I need:

[edge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV1TG.png)

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I should do to get the same result image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB implementation of the sobel edge detection isn't visible so we can only guess exactly what is happening. The only hint we get is from the documentation on `edge` states that when the `'sobel'` option is used then

> Finds edges at those points where the gradient of the image I is
>   *maximum*, using the Sobel approximation to the derivative.

It's not stated, but taking the maximum of the gradient is more complicated than simply taking the local maximums in the image. Instead we want to find local maximums with respect to the gradient direction. Unfortunately the actual code used by MATLAB for this operation is hidden.

Looking at the code that is available in `edge` it appears that they use 4*mean(magnitude) for the threshold in the thinning operation so I'm using this combined with your fudge factor. The `orientated_non_max_suppression` function is far from optimal but I wrote it for readability over performance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters

gray_image = cv2.imread('cell.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(dtype=np.float32)

def orientated_non_max_suppression(mag, ang):
    ang_quant = np.round(ang / (np.pi/4)) % 4
    winE = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0]])
    winSE = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 1, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1]])
    winS = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0]])
    winSW = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 0],
                      [1, 0, 0]])

    magE = non_max_suppression(mag, winE)
    magSE = non_max_suppression(mag, winSE)
    magS = non_max_suppression(mag, winS)
    magSW = non_max_suppression(mag, winSW)

    mag[ang_quant == 0] = magE[ang_quant == 0]
    mag[ang_quant == 1] = magSE[ang_quant == 1]
    mag[ang_quant == 2] = magS[ang_quant == 2]
    mag[ang_quant == 3] = magSW[ang_quant == 3]
    return mag

def non_max_suppression(data, win):
    data_max = scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(data, footprint=win, mode='constant')
    data_max[data != data_max] = 0
    return data_max

# compute sobel response
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray_image, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray_image, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
mag = np.hypot(sobelx, sobely)
ang = np.arctan2(sobely, sobelx)
# threshold
fudgefactor = 0.5
threshold = 4 * fudgefactor * np.mean(mag)
mag[mag < threshold] = 0
# non-maximal suppression
mag = orientated_non_max_suppression(mag, ang)
# alternative but doesn't consider gradient direction
# mag = skimage.morphology.thin(mag.astype(np.bool)).astype(np.float32)

# create mask
mag[mag > 0] = 255
mag = mag.astype(np.uint8)
```

### Results on the Cell

**Python**

[image]

**MATLAB**

[image]

---

### Results on MATLAB's peppers.png (built-in)

**Python**

[image]

**MATLAB**

[image]

---

The MATLAB implementation must use something a little different but it looks like this gets pretty close.